# Understanding recursively defined error in NuSMV

Tags: logic, nusmv

I have a piece of code in NuSMV which has sprung an error. The code is:-

```
MODULE main
VAR
    x1: {a,b,c,d,e};
    x2: {a,b,c,d,e};
ASSIGN

    next(x1) := case
        x1=a & x2=c: e;

        x1=d & next(x2)=c : a;
        TRUE : x1;
    esac;
    next(x2) := case
            x1=b & x2=b: c;

            x2=d & next(x1)=e : e;
            TRUE : x2;
        esac;
```

So when I compile this in NuSMV, it gives an error: `recursively defined: x1`

Now I can easily take care of this error by removing next statements associated with x2 for the transition rule of x1, meaning I replace `x1=d & next(x2)=c : a;` with `x1=d : a;` or `x1=d & x2=d : a;`

I want to understand the mechanics of the NuSMV software which is causing the error and why the above fix resolves the error. I think it has got something to with synchronous implementation blah blah blah which I don't understand. Can someone give a precise detailed technical explanation?

And also explain why there is no error with variable `x2`. Its transition rules are aslo defined using the next operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler than that.

You have a circular dependency, and the software cannot resolve that for you.

```
next(x1) := case
     ... & next(x2) : ...
esac;

next(x2) := case
     ... & next(x1) : ...
esac;
```

How is the computer (or a human being) supposed to decide the values of `x1` and `x2` in the next state, when deciding such assignments requires knowing the answers in advance?

---

You violated the so-called **circular dependency rule**, as indicated in the [docs](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/userman/v26/nusmv.pdf), section 2.3.8

> **Rules for assignments**
>
> Assignments describe a system of equations that
>   say how the FSM evolves through time. With an arbitrary set of
>   equations there is no guarantee that a solution exists or that it is
>   unique. We tackle this problem by placing certain restrictive
>   syntactic rules on the structure of assignments, thus guaranteeing
>   that the program is implementable.
>
> The restriction rules for assignments are:
>
> - The **single assignment rule** – each variable may be
>     assigned only once.
> - The **circular dependency rule** – a set of
>     equations must not have “cycles” in its dependency graph not broken by
>     delays.
>
> [...]
>
> If we have an assignment like `x := y ;`, then we say that *x depends on
>   y*. A *combinatorial loop* is a cycle of dependencies not broken by
>   delays. For instance, the assignments:
>
> ```
> x := y;
> y := x;
> ```
>
> form a combinatorial loop. Indeed, there is no fixed order in which we can
>   compute `x` and `y`, since at each time instant the value of `x` depends on
>   the value of `y` and vice-versa
>   We can introduce a *“unit delay dependency”* using the `next()` operator.
>
> ```
>       x := y;
> next(y) := x;
> ```
>
> In this case, there is a unit delay dependency
>   between `x` and `y`. A combinatorial loop is a cycle of dependencies whose
>   total delay is zero. In NUSMV combinatorial loops are illegal. This
>   guarantees that for any set of equations describing the behavior of
>   variable, there is at least one solution.
>
> [...]

---

You ask:

> [...] why the above fix resolves the error.

It fixes the error because it breaks the *combinatorial loop*. After the change, the software still needs to compute the future value of `x1` in order to compute the future value of `x2`. However, to compute the future value of `x1` now it no longer needs to know the future value of `x2` (or any other unavailable information, for all that matters), so it can resolve both assignments.

---

You ask:

> And also explain why there is no error with variable x2. Its transition rules are aslo defined using the next operator.

Both assignments on `x1` and `x2`, taken independently, are perfectly legal. However, the error is not on a single assignment but rather on the combination of these two assignments. Since there is only one *circular dependency*, involving *two variables*, the error gets reported only once as soon as it is spotted. So it doesn't really matter whether you fix it by changing the assignment over `x1` or that over `x2`, as long as there no longer is a cycle in the dependency graph.